# Tengo una duda sobre mandar a llamar una variable en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-sqlite

Tengo una duda en mis campos estoy ocupando lo que viene siendo un edit text donde en el edit text pongo un id para identificar un campo mediante Retrofit - GET que me servira para mandar a llamar a una pagina que contiene campos pero al momento de darle en el button para hacer una consulta individual me muestra esto: path parameter id value must not be null:

este es mi codigo para hacer mi consulta individual mediante retrofit-get

```
btnindividual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//mandamos a llamar a mi consulta individual
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), individual.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


           id = Consulta.getText().toString();
              //  getIndividual();
            }
        }
    });
```

aqui esta mi codigo que recibe el valor de mi consulta individual pero no se si estoy llamando a mi campo de mi edit text porque me marca path parameter id value must not be null:

```
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_individual);
      mJsonTxtView = findViewById(R.id.jsonText);

    getIndividual();
 }
```

Aqui es donde programo todos mis campos para que muestren mis campos como en la consulta general

```
  private void getIndividual() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://huasteco.tiburcio.mx")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MarvelApi MarvelApi = retrofit.create(MarvelApi.class);

    Call<Personajes> call = MarvelApi.getmarvelId(id);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Personajes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Personajes> call, Response<Personajes> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                mJsonTxtView.setText("Codigo: " + response.code());
                return;
            }

            Personajes personaje = response.body();

            String cont = "";
            cont += "id:" + personaje.getId() + "\n";
            cont += "nombreP:" + personaje.getNombreP() + "\n";
            cont += "nombreR:" + personaje.getNombreR() + "\n";
            cont += "descripcion:" + personaje.getDescripcion() + "\n";
            //String foto = personaje.getFoto();
           // Picasso.get().load(foto).into(salida);

            mJsonTxtView.append(cont);

        }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<Personajes> call, Throwable t) {

            mJsonTxtView.setText(t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya me muestra mi consulta general pero en la consulta individual  me muestra lo de arriba porque mi parametro que recibo del textview es nulo  =(

Comment: El parámetro global `id` está null al tu realizar la consulta. Debes asignarle un valor antes de llamar `getIndividual();` en el `onCreate`. La respuesta te dice que esa petición al API no puedes enviar un `ID` como `null`. Verifica la documentación a ese Endpoint y mira cuáles son los escenarios que acepta, si tienes control de Backend o documentación del API. Pero intenta asignarle un valor que no sea `null` a ID antes de consultar en MarvelApi.getmarvelId(`id`).